# TCP congestion control - Congestion avoidance algorithm

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

Does congestion avoidance algorithm start with cwnd>=ssthresh or only with cwnd>ssthresh?

cwnd=Congestion windows
ssthresh=slow start threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementations can choose.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681:
When cwnd and ssthresh are equal, the sender may use either slow start or
congestion avoidance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on the algorithm. There are a lot of congestion control algorithm like TCP Tahoe, TCP Reno, TCP Westwood etc. You can check them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control here. In Reno, if cwnd <= ssthresh then slow start else congestion avoidance.